# Remove line segments that are shared between rectangles

Tags: c#, graphics

The first image is what I have--a list of `Rectangle`s that I'm using to "highlight" a string of characters.  The second image (right) is a mock-up of what I'd like to see.

What would be the best way to remove the shared line segments?

[image: What I have]
[image: What I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I have figured out a decent solution.

```
// create a pen with a width of 2px (half of it will be blanked out so it will
// essentially be a width of 1px)
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2f);

// build a GraphicsPath with the rectangles
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
gp.AddRectangle(...);
gp.AddRectangle(...);
gp.AddRectangle(...);

// g is our Graphics object
// exclude the region so the path doesn't draw over it
Region reg = new Region(gp);
g.ExcludeClip(reg);

// now draw path, it won't show up inside the excluded clipping region
g.DrawPath(pen, gp);

// clean up
g.ResetClip();
pen.Dispose();
gp.Dispose();
reg.Dispose();
```